# What is the best way to compile CSS code and run node server?

Tags: css, express, sass

I only just started learning about SCSS but I'm using it for my current project.

Right now I have these two commands inside my `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www && npm run scss",
  "scss": "sass --watch src/scss/main.scss public/stylesheets/style.css"
},
```

When I use `npm run scss` my SCSS file successfully compiles my CSS. I've tested it multiple times and it works. However, when I use `npm run dev` the only thing that happens is my server starts. I've used both `&` and `&&` symbols inside the command and neither work. I'm wondering if it's just easier to compile my SCSS and then start my server, despite it seeming more of a hassle. Or if there's a more professional way that I don't seem to know yet.